# Merging 2 XML Files with same element and assigning id to unique items

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
I have a pair of XML Files with following structure :

* the data contained here is random

        <root_tag>
        <packages>
         <package>
          <name>class_name1</name>
          <classes>3</classes>
          <functions>21</functions>
          < ncss>285</ncss>
          <javadocs>20</javadocs>
          <javadoc_lines>111</javadoc_lines>
          <single_comment_lines>11</single_comment_lines>
          <multi_comment_lines>222</multi_comment_lines>
    </package>
     </packages>

    <objects>

        <object>
          <name>object1</name>
          <ncss>255</ncss>
          <functions>17</functions>
          <classes>2</classes>
          <javadocs>20</javadocs>
        </object>

    </objects<
    <functions>
    <function>
          <name>function1</name>
          <ncss>242</ncss>
          <ccn>63</ccn>
          <javadocs>1</javadocs>
        </function>
    </functions>
    </root_tag>
```

A package has following data items within it :

name classes functions ncss javadocs javadoc_lines single_comment_lines    multi_comment_lines

An object has following data items associated with it :

name   functions  ncss    javadocs classes

A Function has following data items :

name ncss ccn javadocs

Suppose that my 2nd xml file contains some different values for function1. How do I merge these xml files into a third file and assign a unique id to each name element so the output is as follows :

```
File  Id    Name    Classes  Functions  NCSS JavaDocs JavaDocLines SingleCommentLines

File1 func1 somefun Null     Null       10   20       30           40

File2 func1 somefun Null     Null       11   23        40          50
```

And is there any way to do this through a java program ?

Comment: Use JAXB, whack it into a java datastructure and do what you will. Or do that manually using SAX or StAX.

Comment: @bmorris591 I was hoping to do so using XSLT transforms , as marshalling the xml into objects , then processing them and writing them back in xml form seems to be highly time consuming and for some reason , I cant get the JAXB jars to work with my copy of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT you could achieve it with something like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
<!-- You need to store the other inputs in xsl:variable to access it inside the same
stylesheet -->
<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2.xml')"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"/>   
<xsl:template match="root_tag">
    <!--Open here your personnal layout stuffs,
    like opening tables <table:table> and things like that (column labels...)-->
    <table>
    <labels/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//function | $file2//function">
         <!-- All the work is done by the xsl:sort which can specify the order you
         want to process you elements. -->
         <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- Close here your layout stuffs -->
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="function">
    <!-- Open here your layout inline stuffs-->
    <line>
    <!-- Here you may prefer to apply the templates
         in specific order in case of 'melted' input, 
        do this by calling templates in queue, like  <xsl:apply-templates
        select="name"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="ncss"/>...-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    <!-- Close here your layout inline stuffs -->            
    </line>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This template may apply to anything but he's applied only on function childs
during the process -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- Open here the cell stuffs (<table:table-cell>) -->
    <cell>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <!-- Close here the cell stuffs-->
    </cell>
</xsl:template>
```

I used some dummy elements for the "layout stuffs" (like table, line and cell).

Hope this may help.